# Find the angle of triangle inside circle

Tags: triangles, angle

Let's say I have,

[image]

Now I have to find the angle CBA. Given that we know just 26 given above.

Comment: Think about the measure of $ACB$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\angle ACB$ is 90 degrees because AB is the diameter of the circle.

Answer (score 0):

$\angle CAB=26$ and  $AB$ is a diameter hence $\angle ACB=90$.

So $\angle CBA=180-(90+26)=64$.

Comment: Very neat, +1...